# Best way to dynamically append react Components to the same <div>

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a jQuery autosuggest feature that allows you to search, select, and add your selection to a `<div id="suggested-peers" />`, where you can see all your selected choices thus so far.

```
  select: function(event, ui) {
    var newMember = ReactDOM.render(<MemberThumbnail name={ui.item.value.full_name} title={ui.item.value.title} />, document.getElementById("suggested-peers") );
```

The problem is that every time I make a new selection, the old one is replaced. I've thought of a number of ways to do this, but I'm curious what the best React-style way of accomplishing this would be.

Comment: can you show whole component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much information here, but basically something like:

```js
// Render method of the component that you have ReactDOM.render()ed into
// your document.
function render () {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.members.map(member => <MemberThumbnail
        name={member.full_name} title={member.title}
      />)}
    </div>
  );
}

// Where `this` refers to the component referenced above
select: function(event, ui) {
  this.setState({members: this.state.members.concat(ui.item)});
}
```

Comment: Ahh ok I was thinking that too. So let the `<MemberThumbnail />` component be considered pluralistic, and then have it run through a loop. Then all I need to change is the amount of data it has in it, and then rerender it. Brilliant! Cool, just wanted to make sure this was the best way to do it.

Comment: Would `setState` automagically trigger `MemberThumbnail` to reload?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you might want a `<MemberThumbnails />` or `<Members />` that holds the state (e.g. `members` array) and renders a `<MemberThumbnail />` or `<Member />` for each. Yes, per the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) "This is the primary method you use to trigger UI updates from event handlers [...]. `setState()` will always trigger a re-render unless conditional rendering logic is implemented in `shouldComponentUpdate()`".